# Windows App Certification Kit does not load any app to list

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps, app-certification-kit

I was developing a windows store app and I finished everything up to create app package. I even created the app package. And when i launched the app certification kit from the popping up windows, it starts the W.A.C.K. but gives the following error

```
"The Windows App Certification Kit experienced the following failure while validating your app

The {0} cannot continue testing since the specified Windows Store App was not found. Please verify that the packagefulname is correct."
```

Image 1

[image]

So I manually started W.A.C.K. from the start screen and when I tried to test for app, no app were on the app list.

[image]

I am running Windows 8.1 and Visual Studio 2012 ultimate. I tried to test a app which was successfully passed the test when I had Windows 8. But still it was the same error as image 1

Can anyone help me to fix this error.

Thanks.

Comment: I was able to fix the problem by installing W.A.C.K. 3.0
And who ever did down vote this question, Sir there are so many people who are having the same problem. So please before you down vote, double check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by installing W.A.C.K. 3.0

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/bg127575.aspx

I made a blog post about [it](http://testedandwrote.blogspot.com/2013/09/windows-app-certification-kit-22-fails.html)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have at least one exe which is either appear as the shortcut of your application either on desktop or on the start menu.